# Mouseover and mouseout functions DOM element height colliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

This is my jquery

```
    $('#div1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#div2').css('height','500px');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $('#div2').css('height','200px');
    });
```

I put css transition too for "div2" and div2's original height is 200px.
My problem is when I tried to mouse over its height not increasing. I tried this without mouseout part's code. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style` is not a jQuery function. Use `css`

```
$('#div1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#div2').css('height','500px');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#div2').css('height','200px');
});
```

Also, `css()` does not require `px` units to be specified, so you can just use numbers:

```
$('#div1').mouseover(function(){
    $('#div2').css('height',500);
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#div2').css('height',200);
});
```

*Now that you have fixed that the most likely problem is styling. You will need to show the HTML and css you are using.*

Example with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wyL9ecue/1/

Comment: @Maneesh M S: Can you provide HTML too as it may is likely just a styling issue? perhaps a JSFiddle?

Comment: Its part of my jquery coding. Do I need to paste the code here?

Comment: @Maneesh M S: As you can see from the JSFiddle provided your code now works fine. You can update the JSFiddle with your own css and HTML (as saved from your browser - maybe the Chrome F12 DOM inspector?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maneeshms/g3o2vkr9/ I am not familiar with fiddle. But I set up it. Can you check this with $('#rect3').find('.wrap-box').css('height','409');  and without it. Just hover on green box

Comment: @Maneesh M S: Can you simply explain the overall aim for the page (not just one specific section)? I may be able to offer a simpler solution (there seems to be more code than needed for what I think is actually a relative simply task).

Comment: In mouseout function  I put $('#rect3').css('height','409'); This is affecting to mouseover function too